# How to remove \c from Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to feed my Dataframe to regEx but my Dataframe contains \c so regEx throws an error 
[image]

I try to remove the \c from my data frame using the below code:

```
df.Description.str.replace("\\c","c")
```

above code gives this error:
[image]

But, the same code works fine for the string as you can see below: 
[image]

Is there any way I can replace `\c` to `c`? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please share how your original dataframe looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding one more `\` and `*`

solution: 
`df.Description.str.replace("\\c","c")` instead I used below one `df.Description.str.replace("\\\c*","c")`